# Potential static fault on chassis of system

Tags: power-supply, grounding, troubleshooting, ground-loop, electrostatic

The image attached is to demonstrate the observed behaviour. As the robot nears the push pads to charge, it moves its actuators down to make contact and as the contact is made the internal computer appears to shutdown/restart.

This is not linked to any efuses or power systems failing. There is sufficient current budget to withstand the stall current of the actuator.

Additionally, the system has been tested 100s of times in stationary operation without any failures. It only happens under a specific test where the robot moves to the charger, potentially picking up static. The chassis itself is at ground potential.

The hint which started pointing towards static was that the fault disappeared when a scope was brought in to measure and with the earth reference of the scope on ground the failure never happened. When I removed the earth reference of the scope (just to make sure it has nothing to do with the small capacitance the probes might be introducing) the issue came back. So in summary, the earth reference introduced by the scope fixes this failure.

The push pads for the purpose of this test were not plugged into any charger. It was simply 2 metal pieces floating and the failure is still repeatable, so it is not linked to the charger, either.

I have been unable to trigger anything on the scope.  Each time the failure happens, the output always appears to be good except one time where as the contact was made and the computer tripped, Icaptured this.

The pink 12V Fu is the output to the computer. The blue is the 12V rail itself. Yellow is the battery voltage and the green is a current clamp across the fuse output (set to a 5A limit.)

Any suggestions where I should be looking? My guess is the robot is picking up static and as soon as it makes contact with the contacts that static is somehow flowing through the system and tripping things. Should I disconnect the robot from chassis?

All systems internal to the robot are on a common ground.

The connection to the chasis is made by 2 antennas on opposite corners of the robot.

Efuse5_12V is powering the computer[image]

Update: If the metal contacts are replaced with a non conductive part, the issue disappears.

[image]

[image]

Comment: "All systems internal to the robot are on a common ground." Well the first thing I would suspect is that this is not the case. Investigate _how_ things are grounded to chassis. Also what's there on the 12V to protect against spikes and surges? Schematics, please.

Comment: Added additional information which hopefully helps.

Comment: "The connection to the chasis is made by 2 antennas on opposite corners of the robot." Your electronics ground need to be connected to minus somewhere near the supply (assuming battery). Then antennas shouldn't be the only chassis connection or you risk leading noise in that direction. Nor should the chassis be the only ground or you'll get ground currents. The way to combat ESD in general is to ground everything down, _not_ to disconnect things from ground. All conducting metal parts should ideally be grounded to chassis.

Comment: @Lundin The 'circuit ground' is found on the main power board. The antenna forming 
the chassis ground was not a design feature but rather identified late, the fixture securing the antenna to the edge of the robot was also connecting circuit ground to chassis. I noticed the chassis was at ground potential once antennas were connected. Would it be sensible at this point to prevent the chassis ground connection (plastic part around the antenna)?

Comment: Antennas need ground planes to function...

Comment: Of course. Ignore the foolishness.  Ideally i need to ground to the chassis near where the battery and main circuit ground is. Will have to figure this out.

Comment: For now i ran a cable from the chassis to the earth (floor underneath) and it removes the issue of the computer turning off. Obviously this only proves the source of the issue, i still  need a working solution.

Comment: I am particular interested in the connection between chassis and “ground” of the robot. This could communicate both ways. If you google Roomba static discharge you can find a solution the competitor incorporated.

Comment: Here: https://www.sevarg.net/2018/12/30/roomba-i7-teardown-with-the-waving-cat/ find the esd keywords

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is necessarily conjecture, but hopefully makes sense.

IF the problem is caused by static discharge then you may be able to provide a grounding probe that makes contact first - probably with a series resistor to limit peak currents but allow adequately rapid discharge.  A "trail strap" from the robot chassis may help - either just to local surface of perhaps to a ground plate as the charger is approached. This would usually either be high resistance or have a series resistor.

If the charger target is NOT the final one and is floating the two metal pads may be providing a capacitor for ESD. Grounding them via a resistor in the order of 1 megohm may help.

---

**Grounding probe:**

The grounding probe would be as Aaron also suggests - A contact that makes first between robot ground and supply ground.

JUST extending the negative probe first **MAY** help as any static discharge MAY not flow via the positive rail, but ideally you add a 3rd contact with a series resistance that connects from robot ground to charger ground before the main circuit does.

This is a reasonably common arrangement where ESD is a major issue.

Comment: I am not sure i fully follow. How would i introduce a grouding probe? The only contact the robot has (besides the wheels) to the outside is through two metal contacts extending to make a connection with the pads.

Comment: The target is the final one. The point i was making was whether it is floating or not, it fails.

Comment: The grounding probe would be as Aaron also suggests - A contact that makes first between robot ground and supply ground. JUST extending the negative probe first MAY help as any static discharge MAY not flow via the positive rail, but ideally you add a 3rd contact with a series resistance that connects from robot ground to charger ground before the main circuit does. This is a reasonably common arrangement where ESD is a major issue.

Answer (score 0):

@Hasman404 Can you add a third contact, that contacts the metal plate negative side first?  Just have it stick a little lower so it contacts first.  Have it connect to the chassis via ~10k - 100k.  That will equalize the static.

Also, you could try putting a surge protection device on the power rails. Like a MOV or TVS diode.  These devices conduct when their threshold voltage is exceeded, thus shunting the excess charge away from the rest of the circuit.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fivJb8.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: I could look into making the negative connect first. Connect the 100k from the negative to the chassis? Is that the same as connecting a 100k between the chassis and circuit ground inside the robot?

Comment: @Hasman404 It's similar, but by doing it at the contact area you prevent it from propagating around your circuit boards first.